# how to upgrade to MySQL to 5.6.0 or higher from 5.5 on Rasbian (RaspberryPi, ARM)

Tags: mysql, magento, raspberry-pi, raspbian, debian-jessie

I was installing Magento (E-commerce platform) on my Raspberry Pi 3 (Raspbian Pixel), which I used as a server.

I have installed PHP5, MySQL-Server v5.5.
But Magento requires version 5.6.0 or higher of MySQL server, I am unable to update it through apt-get command. also there is no build on official site for ARM architecture (Debian, Jessie).

Please help me upgrading MySQL server.
If compiling the source code is the only way, guide me how-to.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no official build for MySQL 5.6.0 for ARM but there is MariaDB available for ARM which exactly MySQL, [learn more](https://www.androidchirag.com/2017/06/26/mariadb-top-reasons-migrate-mysql/).

Directly Migrating to MariaDB from MySQL cause services error on pi on restart.
I recommend to remove MySQL & other MySQL things like phpadmin completely first.
Make sure to make backup.

Remove PHPmyADMIN

```
sudo apt-get remove -purge phpmyadmin
```

Remove MySQL

```
sudo apt-get remove -purge mysql-common
```

This will remove every thing related to MySQL like mysql-server,etc

Install MariaDB

```
sudo apt-get install mariadb-server
```

Then either restart Apache server

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

or restart Raspberry Pi

```
sudo shutdown -r 00
```

That's All.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL 5.6 should be available on `stretch` for Raspberry. So the easiest way is to use that version or make an upgrade to that version.

http://buildd.raspbian.org/status/logs.php?pkg=mysql-5.6&arch=armhf

there are some packages but they are for stretch. If you need a real dev-system then i would prefer a normal debian or ubuntu.

Comment: why they are so large in size? i.e 4.99 GB